# Python Flask not importing any modules

Tags: python, flask, web-applications

I'm setting up a flask web app and in application.py there are a bunch of import statements.
I have already installed the modules, but whenever I run application.py I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/Doom/Desktop/cirv-backend-flask-master/application.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_migrate import Migrate
ImportError: No module named flask_migrate
```

Is there something I can do to make the modules visible to flask?

edit*

Flask environments are run with flask run, when I call flask run flask runs application.py, as seen below. This then terminates with an error message:

```
 * Serving Flask app "application.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "application", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/Doom/Desktop/cirv-backend-flask-master/application.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_migrate import Migrate
ImportError: No module named flask_migrate

(virtual_environment) User@user % _
```

Comment: Are you launching the flask app in the same environment that the modules are installed?

Comment: I think so, everything  is installed in the same virtualenv in the same directory

Comment: How are you launching the application? If you are not invoking `python app.py` then it might be ignoring the env you're working in.

Comment: I'm running it with flask run, as it's a flask environment.

Comment: It's on the quickstart page of the documentation https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was manually installing all the dependencies for my project after deleting all existing packages in my virtual environment. There were a lot of packages were not included the requirements.txt file of my project. This seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The error statement says:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py"
```

Try running it with Python 3.  If you are using a Mac, you can open terminal, navigate to the project directory, and type:

```
python3 application.py
```

The same command should work in Linux (Arch notably will just be python instead of python3), but I don't know about windows.  It may be that the package is installed/intended for the newer version of Python and is not backwards compatible.

Comment: * Serving Flask app "application.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
This is what flask run looks like

Comment: Do you mean when you run it with python 2 or 3?  Either way, that is what Flask should do.  Type http://127.0.0.1:5000 in your browser to see your web page (your "/" route).  Does this still have the flask_migrate library?

Comment: Hi eric, I updated my post to answer your question. Flask terminates after displaying an error message.

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense to me...  What is Flask run?  You can run a Flask app using python and shouldn't need something else to run it.  Did you create your environment using virtual env?  On a Mac/Linux you can use the command "source /path/to/environment/bin/activate to enter your virtualenv, then just "python3 application.py".  Assuming you have installed flask and flask migrate while the virtualenv was active (double check this), that should work fine.